# Appcelerator studio won't open

Tags: appcelerator

I used Appcelerator to build my mobile application. So today if I try to start Appcelerator studio I have this situation.

[image]

And if I try to click on that screen after some times, I have a windows error like this:

[image]

How can I fix the problem??

I have try to re-download Appcelerator Studio, repair option, modify option, uninstall and reinstall but it doesn't work.

How can I re-open my IDE?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the appropriate place for this question. Your best bet would be to go to the support link for appcelerator studio and see if they have suggestions. Barring that this would probably be better asked (with possibly more details such as OS version and if you have tried compatibility mode) on SuperUser as stackoverflow is more for specific programming issues. This is more of a windows compatibility issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to be you are having a problem with your Appcelerator login. To identify the root cause.

For mac, Go to terminal and run, $`DEBUG=* appc login -l trace`

For windows, `set DEBUG=* && appc login`

What is the error which you are getting here? If you've configured proxy, verify the settings.

Once you are able to login from the command line(CLI), relaunch the studio.

Comment: ok, that command is not for windows, can you send me a command terminal for windows machine?

Comment: @bircastri - Updated the windows command set DEBUG=* && appc login

Answer (score 9):

Try opening a terminal window and doing

```
appc logout
appc login
```

Answer (score 0):

open Terminal in Mac execute command -

> appc setup

After setup completed you could able to login without any issues.